# How can we use the colormatrix only a part of image rather than whole image?

Tags: c#, vb.net, image-processing, gdi+, colormatrix

I know the use of colormatrix. but this work on the whole image. is there any way to work with colormatrix only a part of image rather than whole image.

eg i want to give the brightness of only border area of image.

i am working with c#.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a `ColorMatrix` only works on individual colour vectors/pixels, "all" you need to do is choose your pixels carefully so that they match your criteria.

It's been a while, but if you scan the pixels row by row then the whole of the first and last n rows and the first and last n columns of all the other rows can be transformed.

Answer (score 0):

if:

- bitmap1 is your original bitmap,
- bitmap2 is new bitmap,
- new    Rectangle(100, 50, 20, 20) is a Rectangle you want changes to
  be    made in,
- yourImageAtributes is object of ImageAttributes (I hope you    know
  how to use it):

```
Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(bitmap1.Width, bitmap1.Height); 

//copy bitmap1 to bitmap2  
Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2).DrawImage(bitmap1, 0, 0);

//copy part of bitmap1 to bitmap2 with your own image attributes (ColorMatrix, etc..) 
Graphics.FromImage(bitmap2).DrawImage(bitmap1, new Rectangle(100, 50, 20, 20), 100, 50, 20, 20, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, yourImageAttributes);
```

If you want only border, you can first change whole image, and then copy rectangle of original image inside.